# Update installed PWA in iOS

Tags: ios, angular, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I wrote an PWA project using angular and enabled service-worker on it.
When user installed PWA on iOS (add to home screen) files are cached properly and even when user is not connected to the internet, he/she still can work with PWA app.

The problem is that because of getting files from cache and not from HTTP, the installed PWA will not be aware from updates that happened on the server (html, css and js files)

By considering that service workers are not supported in iOS and i can not use `SwUpdate`, how can i update my installed PWA when there is an update on server?

Answer (score 0):

PWA Updates on IOS depends on the browser used to install it, if it was Safari , then there is no mechanism to automatically update it, other than to uninstall and reinstall.

If PWA was installed on MacOS ( not IOS)  with Chrome browser, the PWA will update as per usual rules.

Reference: [Web.Dev PWA updates](https://web.dev/learn/pwa/update/)